# Using method of unimported class

Tags: python, class, python-import

Consider the following scripts:

`test_import_1.py`

```
class Haha():
def __init__(self):
    self.haha = "Hahahahahahahaha"
    
def laugh(self):
    print(self.haha)
```

`test_import_2.py`

```
def tell_joke(haha):
    haha.laugh()
```

`test_import_3.py`

```
import test_import_1
import test_import_2

haha = test_import_1.Haha()
test_import_2.tell_joke(haha)
```

To my surprise, my EDI did not yell at me that method `.laugh` wasn't defined in `test_import_2.py`, and running `test_import_3.py` did not produce any errors: it just printed `Hahahahahahahaha`.
I thought that if I want to call methods of an object in a script, I had to import the module where the class is defined (in this case, I thought I was expected to import `test_import_1` at the beginning of `test_import_2`), because I thought the `import` statement triggered some kind of check that all the things imported are defined.

Can you explain me what happens in this example? It looks that importing is the same thing as copy-pasting implicitly the piece of code right at the `import`'s spot, without trying to understand anything.

Answer (score 2):

You very often don't import everything you're using. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.now().time()
```

`t` is now of type `datetime.time`, even through we never did `from datetime import time`. It's simply that the class we did import gave us an instance of a class we *didn't* import, and that's fine. It's *objects* being passed around. You only need to import something if you explicitly need to use it as a name, like we used `datetime` in the above example. But if you indirectly get an object from elsewhere, well, that's where you get it from, so you don't need to `import` it.

In your case:

> ```
> def tell_joke(haha):
>     haha.laugh()
> ```

The function `tell_joke` receives an object, and calls the method `laugh` on it. It doesn't need to import the object because it gets it as function argument at call time. There's no specification here what `haha` will be exactly, it just needs to have a method `laugh` so this won't raise an error at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE doesn't know what the type of `haha` is for `tell_joke`, so it can't help you in any way (it can't tell you `laugh` would or would not exist). You could pass in any object that has a `laugh` callable property.

This doesn't really have anything to do with imports, either; you'd see the same with

```
class HahaMachine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.laughter = "Hahahahahahahaha"
    
    def laugh(self):
        print(self.laughter)


def tell_joke(laughing_thing):
    laughing_thing.laugh()
    # haha.laugh() here would also work, because `haha` is in the
    # global scope for this function, but then it would not use
    # the value passed in by the user.


haha = HahaMachine()
tell_joke(laughing_thing=haha)
```

– I purposefully renamed the variables here so they're not shadowing each other, and also purposefully pass the haha machine with a keyword argument (*kwarg*) so you can see how it has a different name in the `tell_joke()` function.

> It looks that importing is the same thing as copy-pasting implicitly the piece of code right at the import's spot, without trying to understand anything.

It's not exactly the same thing (in multiple ways); if you did `import test_import_3`, you couldn't just automagically use `haha` (as if `test_import_3`'s contents had been pasted where you do the import), but you could access `test_import_3.haha` then.

Comment: I thought that in a code like yours, whenever the IDE reads a `.laugh()`, it looks above if at least one thing has a defined method called `laugh`; in the script you give, it does, and thinks "oh, then I can assume that the thing before `.laugh()` is a `HahaMachine`". And, in my situation, in `test_import_2`, I would have expected it to think "oh... nothing above has a method named `laugh`, and we don't import anything, probably the developper has forgotten something...".

Comment: It could assume, but that depends on the IDE. Some IDEs are smart enough to guess across files, some aren't.